# Ball should bounce off the paddles and game should restart once it is gameover

Tags: processing

So this is my entire code and what it does not do, but should definitely do is first bounce off when colliding with the paddles and second if it does not do so then once the game enters in gameover mode once a key is pressed it should restart the game. Now I've tried several things and nothing seems to work.

Can someone please find a solution and try to explain what I did wrong?

```java
// variables for the ball
int ball_width = 15, ball_height = 15;  
int ballX = width/2, ballY = height/2;
//
// variables for the paddles
int paddle_width = 20, paddle_height = 150;
int paddle1 = 60, paddle2;
//
// direction variables
int directionX = 15, directionY = 15;
//
// variables for the score
int scorecounter = 0;
//
//game states
boolean playing = false, gameover = false, finalscore = false, score = true;

void setup () {
  size (1900, 1300); // the field game is going to be 1900x1300 px big
  rectMode (CENTER);
  paddle2 = width - 60;
}



void draw () {
  background (0); // black background

  playing ();
  gameover ();
  finalscore();

}

// 
void playing () {
  if (keyPressed) { 
    playing = true;
  }

  if (!playing) { // playing = false

    fill(255); 
    textSize(80); 
    textAlign(CENTER); 
    text("Press Space to Play", width/2, height/4);

    fill (255); 
    ellipse (width/2, height/2, ball_width, ball_height); // this is the starting point of the ball
    fill (255, 10, 20); 
    rect(paddle1, (height/2), paddle_width, paddle_height);  // red pong
    fill (60, 255, 0); 
    rect(paddle2, (height/2), paddle_width, paddle_height);  // green pong
  }

  if (playing) { // playing = true
    score();

    ballX = ballX + directionX; 
    ballY = ballY + directionY;

    fill (255); 
    ellipse (ballX, ballY, ball_width, ball_height); 

    fill ( 255, 10, 20 ); 
    rect(paddle1, mouseY, paddle_width, paddle_height); // red pong
    fill ( 60, 255, 0 ); 
    rect(paddle2, mouseY, paddle_width, paddle_height);  // green pong

   if ( ballY > height ) { 
     directionY = -directionY;
   } // if the ball reaches the lower wall it will bounce off
   if ( ballY < 0 ) { 
     directionY = -directionY;
   } // if the ball reaches the upper wall it will bounce off

   if ( ballX > width || ballX < 0 ) { 
     gameover = true; }
   }

   if (ballX == paddle1 && ballY <= paddle_height) { 
     directionX = -directionX;
     directionY = -directionY;
   }
   if (ballX == paddle2 && ballY <= paddle_height) {
     directionX = -directionX;
     directionY = -directionY;
   }
}

void gameover () {
  if (gameover) {
    background (0);
  }

  finalscore ();
  score = false;

  if (keyPressed) { 
    playing = true;
  }
}

void score () {
  if (playing) {

    fill(255); 
    textSize(45); 
    textAlign(CENTER); 
    text ( scorecounter, width/2, height/4);

    if (ballX == paddle1 && ballY <= paddle_height) { 
      scorecounter = scorecounter + 10;
    }
    if (ballX == paddle2 && ballX <= paddle_height) { 
      scorecounter = scorecounter + 10;
    }
  }

  if (!playing) {
    score = false;
  }
}

void finalscore () {
  if (gameover) {
    score = false;

    fill(255); 
    textSize(45); 
    textAlign(CENTER); 
    text("Game Over. Press a key to play again.", width/2, height/4);
    fill(255); 
    textSize(80); 
    textAlign(CENTER); 
    text("You scored " + scorecounter + " points", width/2, (height/4) * 3);


    if (keyPressed) { 
      playing = playing;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: ur code is hard to read...

Comment: @jens it is the program processing - so java. but still having in consideration that it is processing we are talking about

Comment: @quemeful any suggestions?

Comment: @Jens Check out the tag. It's a [tag:processing] question.

Comment: @Abigail You haven't actually asked a question. What **exactly** do you expect this code to do? What **exactly** does it do instead? How are those two different? Try to narrow it down to a specific line that isn't doing what you expect it to. As of right now we can't really help you, since your post is much too broad. Please edit it to include a specific technical "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question. And fix your code's formatting while you're at it, because right now it's very hard to read.

Comment: @KevinWorkman done :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the problem, but

```
if (keyPressed) { 
   playing = playing;
}
```

looks not very useful. You have both a function and a variable named `playing`. Reusing identifiers is usually a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue of the ball not bouncing off the paddle, take a look at these lines:

```
if (ballX == paddle1 && ballY <= paddle_height) { 
     directionX = -directionX;
     directionY = -directionY;
}
if (ballX == paddle2 && ballY <= paddle_height) {
     directionX = -directionX;
     directionY = -directionY;
}
```

Notice that you're checking whether `ballX == paddle1` or `ballX == paddle2`. You're checking whether the **exact pixel position** of the ball matches either of the paddles.

However, also notice that you're moving the ball by **15 pixels** each time, so the chances of it hitting an exact pixel are pretty low. In other words, your ball is going to move through the exact pixel position and be **inside** your paddles. **That** is what you have to check for.

Furthermore, you're only checking whether the ball's y position is less than `paddleHeight`. That's not enough. You also have to check whether it's greater than the paddle position!

Even after that, I'm not sure you want to reverse `directionY` when it hits a paddle, but I'll let you decide that for yourself.

For your other question about the gameover not reseting, notice that you never reset the ball position! That means you start playing, but then instantly get a game over. You need to reset the position of the ball before you restart the game.

Honestly, if I were you, I would **start with a more basic sketch**. Your code has a lot of extra stuff in it that doesn't make a lot of sense, so I'm not surprised that you're getting confused. Start with something much simpler: can you create a sketch that simply detects when the mouse is inside a rectangle? Start from there (or even simpler!) and take small steps instead of trying to program your end goal all at once. Good luck.

Comment: I know I should have started with something else but this is an assignment I have to turn in and I figured out how to make the ball bounce off when it reaches the y- axes of the paddle but what I haven't figured out is how I can restrain it to only when the ballX is lower than paddle_height. Could u help me - i'm desperate. I need this project delivered by tomorrow and I have been working on this for two weeks now. This is the only thing left all the other problems are fixed. @KevinWorkman

Comment: @Abigail It might not seem logical, but you'll get your assignment done faster if you start with something simpler. Trying to cram stuff into code you don't really understand isn't going to get you very far. I highly recommend starting smaller and posting a new question with a more specific question. It's really up to you though.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why this is not reseting is because you are never updating the ballX o gameover variable. Every time you press a key you are falling into this conditional.

```
if ( ballX > width || ballX < 0 ) {
  gameover = true; 
}
```

I got around this by adding your inital values to the playing method:

```
void playing () {
  if (keyPressed) { 
    playing = true;
    gameover = false;
    ballX = width/2;
    ballY = height/2;
  }
  // rest of playing() code
}
```

Comment: The `keyPressed` variable is a Processing variable and doesn't need to be defined or initialized. In fact, it **shouldn't** be defined or initialized by the programmer.

Comment: @Kevin Workman I honestly never did any programming with Processing but this made me download and IDE and watch some videos.

Comment: Processing is really fun. Let me know if you have any questions!